# How make [UIView animateWithDuration: ..] work in application porting by apportable?

Tags: uiviewanimation, apportable

On portal application by apportable I need to make some animation (move/scale/change alpha) of UIView *object via call:

```
[UIView
 animateWithDuration:1.f
 delay:0.5f
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
 animations:^(void)
 {
     myview.center    = moveTo;
     myview.transform = transformTo;
     myview.alpha     = alphaTo;
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [self animationFinished];
 }];
```

For now it's only make delay, then execute animation code & completion code immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for answer.
But I need animation "today", so I make next class.
It's work not good enoght, but it's much better then nothing.
Maybe for one it will be helpful

**AOTAnimate.h**

```
//
//  AOTAnimate.h
//
//  Created by Andrei Bakulin on 18/11/2013.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AOTAnimate : NSObject
{
    UIView          *view;

    NSInteger       animationTicksLeft;
    CGFloat         scaleX;
    CGFloat         scaleY;

    CGPoint         moveDelta;
    CGSize          scaleCurrent;
    CGSize          scaleDelta;
    CGFloat         alphaDelta;

    void (^completeAction)();
}

@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGFloat                 duration;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGFloat                 delay;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGFloat                 frequency;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   UIViewAnimationOptions  options;

@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGPoint                 moveFrom;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGAffineTransform       transformFrom;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGFloat                 alphaFrom;

@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGPoint                 moveTo;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGAffineTransform       transformTo;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGFloat                 alphaTo;

+ (AOTAnimate*)makeAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view_ duration:(CGFloat)duration_;
+ (AOTAnimate*)makeAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view_ duration:(CGFloat)duration_ delay:(CGFloat)delay_;

- (void)run;
- (void)runWithCompleteAction:(void (^)(void))complete_;

@end
```

**AOTAnimate.m**

```
//
//  AOTAnimate.m
//
//  Created by Andrei Bakulin on 18/11/2013.
//

#import "AOTAnimate.h"

@implementation AOTAnimate

@synthesize duration, delay, frequency, options;
@synthesize moveFrom, transformFrom, alphaFrom;
@synthesize moveTo, transformTo, alphaTo;

+ (AOTAnimate*)makeAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view_ duration:(CGFloat)duration_
{
    return [self makeAnimationOnView:view_ duration:duration_ delay:0.f];
}

+ (AOTAnimate*)makeAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view_ duration:(CGFloat)duration_ delay:(CGFloat)delay_
{
    return [[AOTAnimate alloc] initWithView:view_ duration:(CGFloat)duration_ delay:(CGFloat)delay_];
}

//----------------------------------

- (void)dealloc
{
    [view release];

    if( completeAction )
        Block_release(completeAction);

    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initWithView:(UIView*)view_ duration:(CGFloat)duration_ delay:(CGFloat)delay_
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        view            = [view_ retain];
        duration        = duration_;
        delay           = delay_;

        frequency       = 0.025f;
        options         = UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

        moveFrom        = view.center;
        transformFrom   = view.transform;
        alphaFrom       = view.alpha;

        moveTo          = view.center;
        transformTo     = view.transform;
        alphaTo         = view.alpha;
    }
    return self;
}

//----------------------------------
#pragma mark - Run animation

- (void)run
{
    [self runWithCompleteAction:nil];
}

- (void)runWithCompleteAction:(void (^)(void))complete_
{
    view.center    = moveFrom;
    view.transform = transformFrom;
    view.alpha     = alphaFrom;

#ifndef ANDROID

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:duration
     delay:delay
     options:options
     animations:^(void)
     {
         view.center    = moveTo;
         view.transform = transformTo;
         view.alpha     = alphaTo;
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if( complete_ )
             complete_();
     }];

#else

    if( duration <= 0.f )
    {
        [self doAnimationComplete];
        return;
    }

    animationTicksLeft = ceil( duration / frequency );

    if( animationTicksLeft == 0 )
    {
        [self doAnimationComplete];
        return;
    }

    moveDelta   = CGPointMake( (moveTo.x-moveFrom.x)/animationTicksLeft, (moveTo.y-moveFrom.y)/animationTicksLeft );
    alphaDelta  = (alphaTo-alphaFrom)/animationTicksLeft;

    CGSize scaleFrom = CGSizeMake( [self scaleX:transformFrom], [self scaleY:transformFrom] );
    CGSize scaleTo   = CGSizeMake( [self scaleX:transformTo],   [self scaleY:transformTo]   );

    scaleDelta  = CGSizeMake((scaleTo.width - scaleFrom.width)/animationTicksLeft,
                             (scaleTo.height - scaleFrom.height)/animationTicksLeft );

    scaleCurrent = scaleFrom;

    if( complete_ )
    {
        completeAction = Block_copy(complete_);
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(doAnimationTick) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];

#endif
}

//----------------------------------
#pragma mark - Manual animation

#ifdef ANDROID

- (void)doAnimationTick
{
    if( CGPointEqualToPoint( moveDelta, CGPointZero ) == NO )
    {
        view.center = CGPointMake( view.center.x + moveDelta.x, view.center.y + moveDelta.y );
    }

    if( CGSizeEqualToSize( scaleDelta, CGSizeZero) == NO )
    {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( scaleCurrent.width, scaleCurrent.height );
        scaleCurrent.width  += scaleDelta.width;
        scaleCurrent.height += scaleDelta.height;
    }

    if( alphaDelta != 0.f )
    {
        view.alpha = view.alpha + alphaDelta;
    }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    animationTicksLeft--;

    if( animationTicksLeft > 0 )
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(doAnimationTick) withObject:nil afterDelay:frequency];
    }
    else
    {
        [self doAnimationComplete];
    }
}

- (void)doAnimationComplete
{
    view.center    = moveTo;
    view.transform = transformTo;
    view.alpha     = alphaTo;

    if( completeAction )
        completeAction();
}

//----------------------------------
#pragma mark - Helpers

- (CGFloat)scaleX:(CGAffineTransform)t
{
    return sqrt(t.a * t.a + t.c * t.c);
}

- (CGFloat)scaleY:(CGAffineTransform)t
{
    return sqrt(t.b * t.b + t.d * t.d);
}

#endif

@end
```

Use like this:

```
UIView *someview;

AOTAnimate *animate = [AOTAnimate makeAnimationOnView:someview duration:1.f delay:0.5f];

// allow to assign - animate.moveFrom / .tranfromFrom / alphaFrom properties,
// but by default they are copy from UIView* object

animate.moveTo      = CGPointMake( 100, 200 ); // new point where need to move
animate.transformTo = CGAffineTransformScale( CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.5f, 1.5f );
animate.alphaTo     = 0.5f;

[animate runWithCompleteAction:^{
    NSLog(@"Animation done..);
}];
```

If this method will run on iOS device - it'll use normal [UIView animateWithDuration:...] method

PS: This class do only "move" from one center point to another. Transform use only to scale object (not move). Alpha on my 2 test devices not supported, but maybe some where it does.

Answer (score 0):

Animations do not work on the current version of Apportable's UIKit.  We have fully functioning animations coming in the next version of UIKit, though.  We will be releasing that once we are satisfied with the quality and coverage.